# I am getting null value when I get data from API using c#

Tags: c#, api

Can Any body tell me what is the error in the code

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Look for a symbol in the latest message of a given channel.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="discordToken">User Discord token</param>
    /// <param name="channelId">Channel ID to scrape/param>
    /// <returns>Returns the found symbol or null</returns>
    private static string ScrapeChannel(string discordToken, string channelId)
    {
        // Look for something that starts with a '$' followed by 2 to 5 alphabetic characters.
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\$)[a-zA-Z]{2,5}");
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/" + channelId + "/messages?limit=1");

            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", discordToken);
            req.Accept = "*/*";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Method="GET"

            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

            }
            Stream dataStream = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string resJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Message[] msg = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Message[]>(resJson);
            Match match = regex.Match(msg[0].content);
            res.Close();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            if (match.Success)
            {
                // Remove '$' character
                return match.Value.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Utilities.Write(ConsoleColor.Red, "ERROR: Could not get Discord message. Error code: " + ex.Status);
            return null;
        }
    }

ScrapeChannel('TOKEN_OF_DISCORD', 'CHANNEL_ID')
```

..................................................
**regex.Match(msg[0].content)--- It shows null value. It should return a String.For example msg[0].content gives the value "THE COIN IS #NXS". And regex.Match is showing null  ** ...........

Comment: Why did you tag this with `c`?

Comment: And what is the error status that it's catching? Have you looked at the *message* for the exception as well as the status? Please provide us with more information.

Comment: @JonSkeet I debug the code and console the values one by one and I Found that null value is returning from the line "Match match = regex.Match(msg[0].content);".....

Comment: @JonSkeet The value of msg[0].content is not null but when it is passed into regex.Match it shows null (means nothing)

Comment: You still haven't told us what the error is, and it should be in the *question* rather than in comments. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/. In particular, read your question to yourself and try to imagine you were wanting to answer it - what would you understand from "I get the error from the line" - which line? What error?

Comment: Actually the value returned from msg[0].content is "The coin is #NXS". Then regex is used to filter the String value which is returned. It should return "NXS" only

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated my question. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Okay, so there's no error after all... and it looks like this has nothing to do with the API involved, but is *just* about regular expression matching. Please rewrite the question with a [mcve] - I suspect it can be a console application with a Main method that's about 4 lines long, with hard-coded input.